# Storing value in memory node js

Tags: node.js, express

I use a request to return a value in node js. I would like to store the value return in memory in node js. Besides, the value should be initialize on app start. How could it be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store items in memory really simply using the `memory-cache` module like so:

```
var cache = require('memory-cache');

cache.put('foo', 'bar');

// will print 'bar'
console.log(cache.get('foo'))
```

Comment: if maxAge is undefined, does it means it will expried only if server is restart?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of cache library for Node.js. I usually use [lru-cache](https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache) when i need one.

```
var LRU = require("lru-cache")
  , options = { max: 500
              , length: function (n, key) { return n * 2 + key.length }
              , dispose: function (key, n) { n.close() }
              , maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 }
  , cache = LRU(options)
  , otherCache = LRU(50) // sets just the max size

cache.set("key", "value")
cache.get("key") // "value"

// non-string keys ARE fully supported
var someObject = {}
cache.set(someObject, 'a value')
cache.set('[object Object]', 'a different value')
assert.equal(cache.get(someObject), 'a value')

cache.reset()    // empty the cache
```